# Can single fermion get converted into single boson?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, conservation-laws, fermions, bosons

Can a fermion get converted into a boson?

Comment: Here's a thing, may be this question does not show research effort but what if the questioner wants to know so that (s)he can learn and use your answer to know something more and cite the answer in his/her research paper. You can close the question and if you don't know the answer why do you temper the level of the question?

Comment: https://www.quora.com/Are-there-any-known-or-proposed-theoretical-processes-to-convert-bosons-to-fermions-or-fermions-to-bosons#:~:text=question%20was%20meant.-,For%20instance%2C%20two%20fermions%3A%20an%20electron%20and%20a%20positron%2C,produce%20an%20electron-positron%20pair.&text=What%20is%20a%20boson%20particle%3F

Comment: ↑ one of the reasons Quora is competing

Comment: It depends on what you are asking. For example in electron positron annihilation two fermions (the electron and positron) are converted to two bosons (the two photons). Would this constitute an answer to your question?

Answer (score 2):

No. That would violate conservation of angular momentum.

Comment: Glad you gave answer.

Comment: Why? Please add some details to this answer.